# Set xml file from sd card as layout in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

In my application i want to get layout file from server and set that file as content view of activity.I want to know whether it is possible..For this what i had in mind is I'll download file from server and will store it in SD card and will access it from there.But is it possible to set the file as content view..Please help me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**No,Its not possible.**

To set xml file as layout in your activity you have that file in `res/layout` directory and also make sure its id entry in `R.java` files.

Without keeping it in `res/layout` you can't apply it as a layout to your activity.

**EDIT:**

Basically when you put any `xml layout` file in `res/layout` then its id entry created in    `public static final class layout` in `R.java` files, And from there when you set that file as a `contentView()` of your activity or `inflate` it, the android nutshell make a view from that raw layout xml file and apply it to your activity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer...Just another question..i want to set the layout dynamically in android is that possible anyway??and what is my layout from server contains all the necessary information to set the layout....can u help me with this?

Comment: I think if you put the necessary information about creating a layout in file at server side, then in android application make a java code for making a dynamically views and in that java code use those information (from server side file) and make the appropriate views and set it dynamically..

Comment: yes...that could be done...but then would increase my processing time right?

Comment: ok...i would rather stick to the basics of android then since my layout files are much bulky....thank u so much for your answer...